Plotting polarization of EM waves in Matlab
There is a polarization matrix I want to implement in Matlab.
I have built a basic Matlab plot which could visualize EM waves in 3D.
The basic equations described in equation $(2.5.1)$ from the attached link.
Given the simple case of linear polarization, what is the strategy of plotting $(2.5.1)$ EM representation like in the photo below?
https://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ewa/ch02.pdf

clc
clear
x = linspace(0,4*pi,100);
figure;
plot3(x,zeros(1,100),zeros(1,100),'k','LineWidth',2);
hold on
plot3(x,-sin(x),zeros(1,100),'k');
plot3(x,zeros(1,100),sin(x),'k');
x_quiver = 0:pi/4:4*pi;
q1 = quiver3(x_quiver,zeros(1,17),zeros(1,17),zeros(1,17),-sin(x_quiver),zeros(1,17),0);
q2 = quiver3(x_quiver,zeros(1,17),zeros(1,17),zeros(1,17),zeros(1,17),sin(x_quiver),0);
hold off;


I’m voting to close this question because questions about implementation of computational tasks are off-topic on this site.

Hello Michael, Is there a forum for computational electromagnetics you could reccomend.
